# Write bounds for a quantity in terms of bounds on another quantity

Tags: recreational-mathematics, boundary-value-problem

I have an expression that gives me the bounds for a certain variable `X` in terms of another variable `Y`. How can I write these bounds as a function of bounds of `Y`?

Specifically, if
$$X \in \lbrack max(0,Y-1), min(1,Y)\rbrack$$
and
$$Y \in \lbrack a, b\rbrack$$
How do I find f(.) and g(.) in the expression below?
$$X \in \lbrack f(a,b), g(a,b)\rbrack$$

Note that:

- X is a probability, so $X\in\lbrack0,1\rbrack$
- Y is sum of 2 probabilities, so $Y\in\lbrack0,2\rbrack$. This does not mean that a=0 and b=2 but that $\lbrack a,b\rbrack \subseteq \lbrack0,2\rbrack$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have, rewriting the first two bounds you have:
$$
\begin{align}
X \geq Y-1, \ X\geq 0 \\
X \leq 1,\ X \leq Y \\
a\leq Y \leq b
\end{align}
$$

so that
$$
a-1 \leq Y - 1 \leq X \leq b
$$
and overall
$$
\max(a-1, 0) \leq X \leq \min(1,b).
$$

Comment: the bounds you wrote are looser than the previous ones on X though, is this a consequence of the fact that I have bounds on Y instead of an exact value?

Comment: Well, you have to lose something... For instance, if at tell you that $X=Y$ but only that $Y\in[0,1]$, a bound on $X$ in terms of $Y$ is pretty accurate (interval which is a singleton), but there is not nothing more you can say than $X\in[0,1]$ if you only allow me to use $0$ and $1$.